# What's best practice for creating entity objects in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I am building a REST API and I have entity classes like:

```js
@Entity()
export class Thing {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  @IsNotEmpty()
  @Column()
  name: string;

  @IsNotEmpty()
  @Column()
  description: string;
}
```

I've realized that there are at least two ways of creating an object (object literal, and using a constructor). I mostly use the object literal method in my code because typescript will catch if I am creating an improper object. For example:

```js
// will throw an error because name is required
const thing: Thing = {
  id: 'xyz',
  description: 'description'
};
```

But sometimes, I only need to create an object that has a subset of the properties. For example, in unit tests, maybe the specific test only cares about the id of the thing. Or if I am taking a CreateThingDTO from a request at POST /api/things, the DTO will not have an id because the id gets generated by the database on insert. In those cases, I would do:

```js
// in unit tests
const thing = new Thing();
thing.id = randomUUID();

// if I need to manipulate an object before it gets saved to the database
const thing = new Thing();
thing.name = dto.name;
thing.description = dto.description;
```

1. Is there anything wrong with the way I am doing this?
2. Should I stick to one way or the other?
3. Should I turn id into an optional property `id?: string`?

I originally came from a Java background where I pretty much always defined constructors, made object fields private and created getters/setters (or just used Lombok). In TS/JS, I don't really see anyone doing that.

Comment: You can totally do it the 'Java way' in TS as well. Wether you should do it or not is mostly an opinion, and I recall SO having a policy being mostly about technical problem solving rather than sharing opnions.

On a more technical note, you have the Partial utility type in TypseScript if you want to set properties optional in a specific method/test: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware of the Partial type. I use it for creating DTOs. But in unit tests, if I do something like `thing: Partial<Thing> = { name: 'xyz' }` and try to pass that to `thingService.create(thing)` it complains that thing is missing properties. So I've just been creating full formed objects, and for the properties I don't really care about, do something like `description: expect.any(String)`.

Comment: Right now this question is essentially soliciting opinions and therefore not really on-topic for Stack Overflow. Please [edit] the question so that there's some objective criterion for determining if an answer is correct or incorrect.  I'm not quite sure how you'd do that here, to be honest.